# How do I change the space between system tray icons in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons, notification-area, size

My system tray icon on Win10 suddenly becomes bigger. Originally, it is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBVSS.png

But now it is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF4Mm.png

Each icon occupies larger space (although they are not bigger), and the space between them becomes wider.

How can I make the system tray icons smaller?

Thanks in advance!

---

I have tried to "Change the size of text, apps, and other items"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n09A7.png

and cancelled "Use small taskbar buttons"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLYGl.png

and changed the height of the taskbar,

and changed the settings of tablets.

and reinstall the graphic card driver.

But None of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Download [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker)
- Install and run
- Right-click its traybar icon and select "Advanced options"
- On the OptionsEx tab, scroll-down and find "tray_icons_padding"
- If it's non-zero than this is the source of the problem, so reset it
  to zero.
  Otherwise, you could experiment with some values, such as `5`.
- Click the Apply button to see the changes.

For more information see the article
[Reduce extra space between icons on the taskbar and tray notification area](https://winaero.com/reduce-extra-space-between-icons-on-the-taskbar-and-tray-notification-area/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It really fix this issue. But I notice that after 7+ Taskbar Tweaker exits, the changes made by 7+ Taskbar Tweaker are restored. Is there a way to keep the changes after 7+ Taskbar Tweaker exits? Thanks!

Comment: Some fixes require having 7+ Taskbar Tweaker as a background process. Set it to start with Windows to always have it running.